Google smart action device type window queryOnlyOpenClose
Am using action.devices.traits.OpenClose trait
Am using this sdk - "actions-on-google": "^3.0.0", and "googleapis": "^140.0.1"
I tried to add queryOnlyOpenClose parameter in Sync payload but showing me this error: I think your sdk doesn't support this parameter.
[Cannot find field: queryOnlyOpenClose in message home.graph.sync.DevicesSyncResponse.Device\] while parsing JSON \[{"payload":{"agentUserId":131373,"devices":\[{"deviceInfo":{"hwVersion":"1.0","manufacturer":"ERA Smartware","model":"2024","swVersion":"22072024"},"id":"windowHandle-017034114","name":{"name":"Tree"},"queryOnlyOpenClose":true,"traits":\["action.devices.traits.OpenClose"\],"type":"action.devices.types.WINDOW","willReportState":true},{"deviceInfo":{"hwVersion":"1.0","manufacturer":"ERA Smartware","model":"2024","swVersion":"22072024"},"id":"windowHandle-017034115","name":{"name":"Test115v"},"queryOnlyOpenClose":true,"traits":\["action.devices.traits.OpenClose"\],"type":"action.devices.types.WINDOW","willReportState":true}\]},"requestId":"10389768098200927175"}\]

I tried to add window device type for smart action and my action doesn't support execute command so i added queryOnlyOpenClose  in sync payload while linking but its showing me this:
[Cannot find field: queryOnlyOpenClose in message home.graph.sync.DevicesSyncResponse.Device\] while parsing JSON

How can we solve this?
